# Is it guaranteed that the centroid of a convex polygon will be the intersection points of lines connecting opposite vertices?

Tags: geometry, polygons, centroid

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centroid), the centroid $\mathbf{C}$ of a finite set of points $\mathbf{x}_1, \mathbf{x}_2, \cdots, \mathbf{x}_k$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$ is:

$$
\mathbf{C} = \frac{1}{k} \left( \mathbf{x}_1 + \cdots + \mathbf{x}_k \right)
$$

Is it true that, for convex shapes, $\mathbf{C}$ would also coincide with the intersecting points of lines connecting opposite vertices? Like what I am illustrating in the diagram below.

This statement sounds a bit doubtful for its validity, but I don't really have a solid explanation or arguments to prove/disprove it. Any pointers?

[image]

Comment: That's a convex shape, not concave.

Comment: Sorry - convex. I will fix it now...

Comment: Hint: What would be the opposite vertex in a pentagon?

Comment: If you consider **regular** convex polygons with an even number of vertices (n=2m), yes. Otherwise no.

Comment: @JeanMarie That's too restrictive. Not only regular polygons. Rectangles or rhombus also have the property, for example.

Comment: @jjagmath You are right. I should have ended with "otherwise, one cannot say anything general"...

Comment: @jjagmath Thanks a lot! Feel free to convert it to an answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The property you propose doesn't make sense for example for a pentagon. What would be the opposite of a vertex?

Also, you should be aware that the centroid of a polygon is in general distinct from the centroid of its vertices.

For any triangle, the point where its medians concur is both the centroid of the polygon and also the centroid of its vertices.

For parallelograms, the point where the diagonals intersect is again both, the centroid of the parallelogram and the centroid of its vertices.

But in general, for quadrilaterals, the centroid of the quadrilateral, the centroid of its vertices and the intersection of its diagonals are three distinct points.